# Uninstalling damaged program installation

Tags: 14.04, software-center, uninstall, qt, libraries

I just installed SnmpB MIB browser via Ubuntu Software Center, but installation goes wrong, and there is no program entry in Ubuntu Software Center,although there is a vaste amount of libraries installed in History. Snmpb icon present under Accessories > Internet > SnmpB. How to uninstall program properly with all these libraries? Ubuntu 64-bit, this package wrong.

```
$ dpkg -l snmpb
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  snmpb          0.8          i386         Graphical SNMP MIB browser writte
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt install -f` in a terminal window. It will ask you for your password.

Comment: well, I removed snmpb via `sudo dpkg -r snmpb`, but there is plenty of  `libqt..` listed under 'Ubuntu Software Center' History. This has not been removed.

Comment: are you sure you don't have any other qt programs, like vlc, calibre?

Comment: Yes, I have another similar qt program (qtmib), but all these **libqt** entries in 'History' specified with time when I installed SnmpB and have word "automatic" at the end, so I think it belongs to it?

Comment: Qt is a toolkit library, so it is likely used by more than one program. If you ran `apt install -f` and nothing happened, then those libraries probably just got updated and not installed when you installed that program.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` returned:
"Reading package lists... Done"
"Building dependency tree"       
"Reading state information... Done"
"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded."
Is it possible that these _libqt_ does not belong to qtmib either,  just  been upgraded?

Comment: It is very much possible. Qt, like gtk, is a toolkit library, that is the thing that draws the pretty buttons and menus and themes.

Comment: After running a few commands (apt-get clean,  apt-get autoremove, apt-get autoclean), I tried
`apt-get install -f`  again, it show more 40 packages("The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required.." use "apt-get autoremove" to remove them. Is it safe to remove? (most have `i386` at the end)